# Jabberd2 vs. ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, jabber, ejabberd

I'm thinking about setting up a jabber/xmpp daemon. Now I can't really decide which daemon to use.

I've heard and read that jabberd2 and ejabberd are both good choices, but which one is *better*? Maybe there's even another which can come up with jabberd2/ejabberd?

I'm looking for a rather light-weighted daemon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jabber daemon choice depend really on your requirements.

- ejabberd: pros - lots of features; cons - needs loads of memory
- jabberd2: pros - fast and small; cons - lacking on features
- prosody:  pros - very small, Lua scripted; cons - young thus lacks features

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll go compare memory usage between ejabberd and jabberd2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) today and really liked it. It could be installed from a local user directory, with an embedded database. Configuration via its web-interface was also very quick and intuitive.